# Java SQS Listener with Retryable and NonRetryable Exceptions

Tags: java, amazon-sqs

I have a Java message processor that uses the @SqsListener annotation to listen to AWS SQS messages.

My code inside the processor can generate different exceptions:

- **transient exceptions**: maybe another service is down, and should be a retryable exception. Retry it 3 times, and if all tries fail, move it to the DLQ;
- **permanent exceptions**: a call was not found in the database, and should not be retryable. Move it directly to the DLQ.

I am trying to figure out if I can use specific exceptions to achieve that, without having to create additional code.

I found [this in the AWS documentation](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-lambda-powertools-java/utilities/batch/#move-non-retryable-messages-to-a-dead-letter-queue), but it works only for @SqsBatch.

Comment: What package are you including in your project to get the `@SQSListener` annotation? The only `@SQSListener` annotation I can find is in a deprecated version of Spring Cloud, but it is spelled differently: `@SqsListener`.

Comment: Thank you, I've just fixed it. That's the one we are using.